# Maven: Use the filtering mechanism for text files not under 'resources'?

Tags: maven, filtering, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I need to customize a number of XML files which are not under resources (in particular, they are under an EAR's project src/main/application).

The filtering mechanism would be perfect for this, but my understanding (correct?) is that it works for resources only.

Is there a way to use filtering for files in other directories than src/main/resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filtering in this context means "substituting the tokens like ${project.version} in xml files with the real values"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Maven EAR Plugin can filter the content of `src/main/application`. As documented in [Filtering EAR Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/filtering-sources.html):

> #### [Filtering the sources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/filtering-sources.html)
>
> Filtering the content of `the
>   src/main/application` directory or the
>   one defined by the
>   `earSourcesDirectory` parameter is as
>   easy as:
>
> ```
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.2</version>
>         <configuration>
>            <filtering>true</filtering>
>            [...]
>         </configuration>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
> ```
>
> Note that the standard properties are
>   available for filtering. It is also
>   possible to specify a set of property
>   files to add extra values if
>   necessary. The configuration below
>   uses also the properties defined in
>   `src/main/filters/config.properties`
>
> ```
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.2</version>
>         <configuration>
>            <filtering>true</filtering>
>            <filters>
>              <filter>src/main/filters/config.properties</filter>
>            </filters>
>            [...]
>         </configuration>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Pascal, this works great. I had an older version of the plugin which didn't have filtering.